# Format string - How to edit to format HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#

```
string test = "121410"
```

I want transform this string in string too but with value:

```
test="12:14:10"
```

How can i make this?

Comment: you'll need to transform to `DateTime` first using `DateTime.Parse` and afterwards convert back to string.

Comment: where is the problem ? you can just use simple text operation: take substrings and then join them with colon

Comment: Much simpler solution: `TimeSpan.ParseExact("121410", "hhmmss", null, 0)`

Comment: @Charlieface Perfect solution too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should easily be able to pop the `:` entries in, and remove them again to reverse the function

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "121410";
        
        // original value
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        
        string testFormatted = test.Substring(0, 2) + ":" + test.Substring(2, 2) + ":" + test.Substring(4, 2);
            
        // value in time display format
        Console.WriteLine(testFormatted);
        
        string testUnformatted = testFormatted.Replace(":", String.Empty);
        
        // original value restored from time display format
        Console.WriteLine(testUnformatted);
    }
}
```

Output

```
121410
12:14:10
121410
```